# Why I can't access a property of parent class from child class instance in JS inheritance?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have two classes. I want to access `type` property of Parent from instance:

```js
// Parent class
function Animal() { this.type = 'animal' }

// Child class
function Rabbit(name) { this.name = name }

// I inherit from Animal
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit; // I want to keep Rabbit constructor too

// I instantiate my Rabbit and am trying to access rabbit.type
const rabbit = new Rabbit('Bunny');
rabbit.name // => Bunny
rabbit.type // => undefined. WHY?
```

I know how to solve it and access `type`, but...

```js
// all is the same

// Child class
function Rabbit(name) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments); // Just need to add this line in Rabbit class
  this.name = name 
}

// all is the same

rabbit.name // => Bunny
rabbit.type // => animal
```

...but why it doesn't work in the first example? Is it possible to achieve it without using `Animal.apply`?

Comment: *"Is it possible to achieve it without using `Animal.apply`?"* -- you have to call the constructor of the base class in the constructor of the derived class. This is how OOP works. Otherwise, who is going to initialize `rabbit.type`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you would add `type` to the prototype:

```
  Animal.prototype.type = "animal";
```

Or you could hide the `Animal.apply` call behind the `class` sugar:

```
 class Animal {
   constructor() {
      this.type = "animal";
   }
 }

 class Rabbit {
   constructor(name) {
     super(); // <<<
     this.name = name;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);` only extends the properties defined in the `prototype` chain. The properties defined within the constructor won't get extended.

Try this,

```
...    
Rabbit.prototype = new Animal();
...
```

**Updated Example:**

```js
// Parent class
function Animal() { this.type = 'animal' }

// Child class
function Rabbit(name) { this.name = name }

Rabbit.prototype = new Animal();
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;

const rabbit = new Rabbit('Bunny');
console.log(rabbit.name);
console.log(rabbit.type);
```